# R: Creating a data frame with the name of the .csv file as a row, error in file (file, "rt"): invalid 'description' argument

Tags: r

I have to create a data frame that inlcudes the name of the .csv file I'm reading as a row or an observation and the number of observations of a variable as a column, so far I've done this:

```
REA <- function(directory, grupo = "plantas", ANP){
        filelist <- list.files(path=directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
        especies <- numeric()
        for(i in ANP){
                Dat <- read.csv(filelist[i], header = TRUE)
                especies <- c(especies, nrow(table(Dat$especievalida)))
        }
        data.frame(ANP, especies)
}
```

it doesn't work, it returns an error like this when I put the name of the file I want:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

The idea is that you could be able to put the name of the "ANP" to retrieve that file specifically or you could leave it absent, so that the function retrieves the information of all of the files in the folder.
The names of the files in the folder are like this: "Alto Golfo de California y Delta del Río Colorado", "Balandra", etc.
Am I taking the right approach to deal with this problem? Do I have to define the argument "ANP" with the name of all the 162 files?

Comment: When you do `for(i in ANP)` it will only iterate over the values you pass in via the `ANP` argument. It's unlikely you can use the values to index into `filelist[i]`. I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here because there doesn't seem to be a question in your post and Stack Overflow is a question and answer site.

Comment: You're right I'm sorry, I forgot to write the question, I hope with the edit it's more clear the problem I'm dealing with, thank you for your time